# how to handle error in okhttp3 without crash

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using the following method to handle my requests

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        .let { originalResponse ->

            Log.i("AMIRA999", "code : " + originalResponse.code())

            when (originalResponse.code()) {

                200 -> {
                    Log.i("AMIRA999", "body : " + getErrorResponse(originalResponse))
                    originalResponse
                }
                401, 404 -> {


                    Log.i("AMIRA999", "body : " + getErrorResponse(originalResponse))
                    originalResponse

                    /*return originalResponse.mapToBody(
                        originalResponse.body()?.contentType(),
                        getErrorResponse(originalResponse)
                    )*/
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.i("AMIRA999", "body : " + originalResponse.body().toString())
                    throw BadRequestException()
                }
            }
        }
```

the method work perfect when the code is 200, but it crash if the code is 404 or 401

what I need to keep returning the json comes from server and does not crash to be able to handle it with error message

how can I do that ?

the crash that I got is the following

```
retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 401 UNAUTHORIZED
at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineCallAdapterFactory$BodyCallAdapter$adapt$2.onResponse(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.kt:104)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:129)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: post your `getErrorResponse()`.

Answer (score 2):

You use [**retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter) and the exception throwing is by design. Any non-`2xx` HTTP response such as `401` will throw an exception. You can see this for yourself in the library [source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/retrofit2/adapter/kotlin/coroutines/CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.kt)

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
  deferred.complete(response.body()!!)
} else {
  deferred.completeExceptionally(HttpException(response))
}
```

But this is not a problem. You can still access the response and your JSON by doing `catch (e: HttpException)` and then calling `val yourJson = e.response()?.body() as? YourJson`.

Note that **retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter** is *deprecated* and that you should migrate to *Retrofit 2.6.0* or newer. Then you can prefix your *Retrofit* interface functions with `suspend` so you can write nice idiomatic Kotlin code.

Answer (score 0):

`Retrofit 2` has a different concept of handling `"successful"` requests than `Retrofit 1`. In `Retrofit 2`, all `requests` that can be executed (sent to the API) and for which you’re receiving a `response` are seen as `"successful"`. That means, for these `requests` the `onResponse` callback is fired and you need to manually check whether the `request` is actually `successful (status 200-299)` or `erroneous (status 400-599)`.

If the request finished `successfully`, we can use the `response object` and do whatever we wanted. In case the `error` actually `failed (remember, status 400-599)`, we want to show the user appropriate information about the issue.

**Example**

**`Error Object`**

Let’s assume your API sends a `JSON error body` like this:

```
{
    statusCode: 409,
    message: "Email address already registered"
}
```

**Note:** you can see your `JSON error body` by printing `response.errorBody()`

To avoid these bad user experiences, we’re mapping the response body to a Java object, represented by the following class.

```
class APIError {
  private val statusCode:Int = 0
  private val message:String
  fun status():Int {
    return statusCode
  }
  fun message():String {
    return message
  }
}
```

**`Error Handler`**

```
object ErrorUtils {
  fun parseError(response:Response<*>):APIError {
    val converter = ServiceGenerator.retrofit()
    .responseBodyConverter(APIError::class.java, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))
    val error:APIError
    try
    {
      error = converter.convert(response.errorBody())
    }
    catch (e:IOException) {
      return APIError()
    }
    return error
  }
}
```

**`Error Handler in Action`**

Now you can handle `error` in API `response` using `ErrorUtils` like the following.

```
val call = service.me()
call.enqueue(object:Callback<User>() {
  fun onResponse(call:Call<User>, response:Response<User>) {
    if (response.isSuccessful())
    {
      // use response data and do some fancy stuff :)
    }
    else
    {
      // parse the response body …
      val error = ErrorUtils.parseError(response)
      // … and use it to show error information
      // … or just log the issue like we’re doing :)
      Log.d("error message", error.message())
    }
  }
  fun onFailure(call:Call<User>, t:Throwable) {
    // there is more than just a failing request (like: no internet connection)
  }
})
```

The complete example with a video is here [retrofit-2-error-handling](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling).

Comment: why would you need to repeat the status code in the response body, if the http response is already holding it?